# how to make facebook android app deep links

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, deep-linking, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to create a deep link that will redirect from a url I post on facebook into my android app and I noticed there is something in facebook api called App Links in this link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ but for some reason their docs has been removed and I have not found any possible way to achieve that...

How can I make a deep link from facebook into a specific page in my android app?

Answer (score 0):

Weird that they took it down. Basically you need to implement HTML tags in your web page the link points to. Also you must have URI scheme implemented in your app.

Until the page comes back up I suggest you use their debug site:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

You can scrape this test link got reference:
https://onelink-sim.onelink.me/coiD/simbananas